# Regarding ADO.Net

Tags: ado.net

I have fetched some 1000 records using data adaptor and displayed in the UI(DataGrid).
Now whenever user is changing the value in anyone of the row in the data grid, that 
particular value has to be updated into database table. Currently i am dumping the entire
table again using adaptor.update. i dont want to do that...i just want to update only that
row..how can i achieve this .??  can anybody help regarding this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and pass to adapter only changed rows by calling [DataSet.GetChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we(VS.80).aspx) or [DataTable.GetChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649.aspx) methods